# automatic login to gmail error occuring through firefox

Tags: java, selenium

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Login {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
       driver.get("https://www.mail.google.com");
       driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
       driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("xyz");
       driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
    }
 }
```

I am trying to write a program to login automatically into gmail.
I have tried everything
please help!!!!

This is giving me the error like this:

> Exception in thread "main"   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:com.google.common.
>       base.Platform.precomputeCharMatcher
>       (Lcom/google/common/base/CharMatcher;)
>       Lcom/google/common/base/CharMatcher;
>           at com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.precomputed(CharMatcher.java:664)
>           at com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.(CharMatcher.java:71)
>           at com.google.common.base.Splitter.on(Splitter.java:127)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpCommandCodec.
>              (JsonHttpCommandCodec.java:59)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.
>       (HttpCommandExecutor.java:85)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.
>       (HttpCommandExecutor.java:70)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.
>       (HttpCommandExecutor.java:58)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.
>       start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:87)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient
>       (FirefoxDriver.java:271)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.
>       (RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.
>       (FirefoxDriver.java:218)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.
>       (FirefoxDriver.java:211)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.
>       (FirefoxDriver.java:207)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.
>       (FirefoxDriver.java:120)
>           at com.st.Login.main(Login.java:17)

Comment: It doesn't come from code you posted. Exception points to line 17 (`com.st.Login.main(Login.java:17)`), but code you posted has less lines

Comment: Actually i had some extra codes.

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Gmail {
 public static void main(String[] args){
  WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.mail.google.com");
  driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
  driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("monica");
  driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
 }

}


now this error is being displayed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
 at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>    (SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager    (HttpClientFactory.java:71)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:57)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:60)

Comment: at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient    $Factory.getDefaultHttpClientFactory(ApacheHttpClient.java:252)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.<init>    (ApacheHttpClient.java:229)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory    (HttpCommandExecutor.java:96)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:70)

Comment: at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:58)
 at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start    (NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:87)
 at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
 at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
 at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)

Comment: at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
 at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
 at Gmail.main(Gmail.java:7)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: that URL doesn't go anywhere (at least in my side). You can achieve what you want as follows:

```
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/")
driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("");
driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("");
driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
```